# jQuery AJAX Post not posting data on shared server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a piece of code that allows comments to be added to a php page without refreshing the page etc.

Everything works fine on localhost but the data isn't being sent when I put it on my justhost account to test.

On the shared server, the comment is submitted and the comment displays but none of the posted data is being sent....

The code is below - i'm unsure if this is a problem with the code or a limitation of my hosting....

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var form = $('form');
    var submit = $('#submit');
    form.on('submit', function(e) {
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var business_id = $("#business_id").val(); 
    var dataString = 'comment=' + comment;
    $("#flash").show();
    $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />Loading Comment...');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add_comment.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    $(".qa-message-list").prepend(html);
    $(".qa-message-list:last").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#flash").hide();
    }
    });
    return false;
    }); });
    </script>
```

Comment: are you sure about url its right?

Comment: Yes, everything that should happen happens but the posted data isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Your server may not be able to find the path. Try adding

```
 url: "/add_comment.php",
```

Comment: The path appears to be correct because everything that should happen is happening - i.e. the comment is added but without any of the posted data.

Answer (score 0):

On you live server try using some debugging techniques, such as on form submit alter ('Form is being submitted') etc also try something like firebug to see if you get any errors, you could be missing a file upload or the path to a file is incorrect.